# Perl command works on command line but not within a bash script

Tags: bash, perl, substitution

Within a larger bash script I use a line with a perl command to substitute a time stamp in a text file with the current date and time. I use the following the lines:

```
perlcmd="perl -i -pe 's/2005-03-31T19:13:30/$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")/' ./file.txt"
echo $perlcmd
$perlcmd
```

The echo command shows me that the perl command is okay, its output is:

```
perl -i -pe 's/2005-03-31T19:13:30/2017-12-21T11:33:44/' ./file.txt
```

The time stamp, however, is not substituted. When I paste the echoed line to the command line it is executed properly and the time stamp is substituted. How to I have to change the code in the bash script to make it work?

Comment: Don't put your command in a variable http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 (and if you do anyway, [quote it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the single quotes in prelcmd variable are interpreted literally and not syntacticaly (because of shell command line processing not specific to bash but [posix shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) quoting is before parameter expansion), easiest is to use an array instead :

```
perlcmd=(perl -i -pe 's/2005-03-31T19:13:30/'"$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")"'/' ./file.txt)
echo "${perlcmd[*]}"
"${perlcmd[@]}"
```

another solution is to reinterpret perlcmd using `eval`

```
perlcmd="perl -i -pe 's/2005-03-31T19:13:30/$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")/' ./file.txt"
echo "$perlcmd"
eval "$perlcmd"
```

Following comment: if `$NewTitle` may contain any character including `/`, perl code will break or code can be injected. To avoid this problem data can be passed by parameter or by environment, also if data can be used in a regex pattern and can contain meta character it can be quoted `\Q` .. `\E`:

by parameter:

```
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{$old=shift@ARGV;$new=shift@ARGV}s/\Q$old\E/$new/' "$old_title" "$new_title" ./file.txt
```

by environment:

```
old_title=$old_title new_title=$new_title perl -i -pe 's/\Q$ENV{old_title}\E/$ENV{new_title}/' ./file.txt
```

Comment: Great! And if I want to substitute a string by a string saved in a variable? Let's say the variable NewTitle contains the desired new string. perlcmd=(perl -i -pe 's/OldTitle/$NewTitle/' ./file.txt) does not work, so what other modification is necessary?

Comment: because of single quote preventing parameter expansion , just close single quotes open double then close double open single 's/OldTitle/'"$NewTitle"'/', but code generation, is tricky to maintain and may be not safe regarding code injection